# DART/FLUTTER - Check if a class value has already been instantiated

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class with the following attributes in Dart

```
class StartValue {
    final int id;
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;

    StartValue({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName})
}
```

and Ill initiate that classe with the values:

```
StartValue(
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'First',
    lastName: 'LastName'
)
```

The question is what kind of validation i need to do to never instance a class StartValue with the NAME = 'First' again? Assuming I can only instantiate the class once with firstName = 'First'.

How do I do an instance validation to verify that each instance does not contain the firstName = "First" ?

I have to do something like:

```
StartValues.contains("First")
```

Keep in mind that I have almost 1000 classes instantiated, so I will have to check one by one if the value "First" contains in each class, this is my question

Comment: Is it only the firstName you want to check?

Comment: yes, only firstName

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through every class to check if the firstName is taken, but I recommend using the == operator instead of .contains(). Why would you have 1000 instances? Can you put us in context?

Answer (score 0):

Use a class-static Set of all ids seen so far.  This will be quick to identify whether an item has already been generated.

Something like:

```
class Person {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  static var seenIds = <int>{};

  Person({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  }) {
    if (!seenIds.add(id)) throw ArgumentError('id $id already seen');
  }
}
```

Comment: OP wanted to check the first name, not the id's

Comment: Yeah, trivial change.  I was hacking quickly and wanted a working example, even if it wasn't building to spec.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping thousands of instances / names in memory is bad design as they are way too many instances / names you don't need at that moment. You go for local sql database like [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) or you go for cloud database like [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore) to fetch the user you need and validate it.

If you still want to do it in-memory you can use a factory constructor, a private constructor and a static HashSet to check user instances.

If you need explanation then comment below. Full code example:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class Person {
  final int id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;

  static HashSet<String> allNames = HashSet<String>();

  factory Person({
    required int id,
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
  }) {
    if (!allNames.add(firstName)) {
      throw ArgumentError("Person with firstname $firstName already exists");
    }
    return Person._(id: id, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName);
  }

  Person._({
    required this.id, 
    required this.firstName, 
    required this.lastName
  });
}
```